# Preview of the ringtone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This is my first question, & i am new to iOS Development. I wanted to ask how can i play preview of the ringtone when tapped on a cell in table view on iphone. 
Basically i am trying to write an app which allows downloading of ringtone from my server on iphone, in that i want to add a preview feature, through which person will be able to listen the tone if he likes he will download. then he will be able to set it as ringtone. 
I have managed to get the links of tones, on my server in a table view. now i want to play preview. how can i do that??
Request: please describe as i am newbie. not an advance programmer.

please ignore my mistakes.

Regards,
Malhaar

edit: i am using this code..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                               pathForResource:[[ringArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]getName]
                                               ofType:@"m4r"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    [click play];
    [click release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not too many details given, but at a high level, you would want to do the following:

1) Implement the "tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" delegate method of UITableView in order to respond to touches on the table cells.

2) Obtain the data for the ringtone. You could do this using NSURLConnection.

3) Play the ringtone using AVFoundation, specifically AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: i implemented the method and avaudio player also.. but its not loading.. instead program crashes..

Comment: Is it throwing an exception when crashing, or just EXEC_BAD_ACCESS or the like?

Comment: thank a lot for response i manged to make it work.. i was providing the wrong path.. and AVAudioPlayer only accepts local files. not remote. now looking for playing remote urls.